# Webscrape CNN, injection, beautiful soup, python, requests, HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-injections

Okay, I thought I was crazy because I repeatedly failed at this, but I thought, maybe something is happening with the html that I don't understand.

I have been trying to scrape the 'articles' from cnn.com.

But no matter which way I tried soup.find_all('articles'), or soup.find('body').div('div')...etc with class tags, id, etc. FAIL.

I found this reference: [Webscraping from React web application after componentDidMount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354695/webscraping-from-react-web-application-after-componentdidmount).

I suspect injection in html is why I am having issues.

I know 0 about injection other than 'html injection attacks' from cyber security reading.

I want the articles, but I am assuming I will need to use a tactic similar to the other stack overflow question link above. I do not know how. Links to help documents or specifically cnn scraping would be appreciated.

Or if someone knows how I could get the 'full data' of the html body element, so that I could do some rearranging in my early code of this definition and then just reassign body.

'Or just tell me I'm an idiot and on the wrong track'

```py
def build_art_d(site):
            
    url = site
    main_l = len(url)
    
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    

    print(soup.prettify())
    
    art_dict = {}
    
    body = soup.find('body')
    print(body.prettify())
    div1 = body.find('div', {'class':'pg-no-rail pg-wrapper'})
    section = div1.find('section',{'id' : 'homepage1-zone-1'})
    div2 = section.find('div', {'class':'l-container'})
    div3 = div2.find('div', {'class':'zn__containers'})
    articles = div3.find_all('article')
    
    for art in articles:
        art_dict[art.text] = art.href
    
        
    #test print
    for article in art_dict:
        print('Article :: {}'.format(article), 'Link :: {}'.format(art_dict[article]))
```

Comment: Websites using `React` or any other modern `JS` library, are making all the requests from the clientside. That is, the `HTML` that they send you does not contain the data you want. It just contains links to some `JS` scripts which when executed fetch Data from another server endpoint and only then they append it to the `HTML` . What you could do is use something like `selinium` that can run javascript, but it is quite heavy (you control your browser's screen).

Comment: So essentially, what I want to get is behind another method on initial request and gets filled in when 'fetched'. 'import requests' only takes the initial 'html outline' and saves that for my use.  Thank you for the suggestion to selenium. I am working on getting my Spyder (Anaconda3) Application to recognize where the driver is.

Comment: Countour-Integral, I don't know how to mark comments as solutions, but if I did, then I would add a mark next to your explanation, without it I would not have solved this.

Comment: If the driver gives you issues you can use `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your driver absolute path")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selinium to enable the data to be filled in by the sites javascript. Then use your existing bs4 code to scrape the articles.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.cnn.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```